# Django: Access and Update fields of a Form Class inside __init__ or save functions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a MyModelForm form class for MyModel model class, and I want to generate a random value for a certain field.

The way I see it is either inside **init** or save functions, I tried using self.fields['randfield'] but it throws an error `'MyModelForm' object has no attribute 'fields'`.

How can I access and update a field inside form class so that I can instantiate it with a random value?

Thanks.

EDIT: After using `self.fields['randint'].initial` I am getting a KeyError. The code is

Okay, here goes:

```
def __init__(self, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
    _fields = ('username', 'email')
    _initial = model_to_dict(instance.user, _fields) if instance is not None else {}
    super(UserDetailsForm, self).__init__(initial=_initial, instance=instance, *args, **kwargs) 
    self.fields.update(fields_for_model(User, _fields))
    self.fields['randint'].initial = '987654321'
```

Comment: This looks problematic,  you are passing in initial values for fields you have not defined yet and also passing in initial values for a data bound form (i.e. when instance is not null).  You probably want to just add fields to the Form for username and email and save them to instance.user in the forms save() method.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like this:

```
class RandomValueForm(ModelForm):
    myfield = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RandomValueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].initial = my_random_generator()
```

Comment: I'm getting a KeyError for the field name, although it is the same as in the model!

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of the non-working code?   The code above should work.

Comment: Ok check my question edit for the code that throws the KeyError

Answer (score 2):

You got this error because you would have tried accessing `fields` on `self` without calling the `__init__` of superclass. So, first you need to call superclass `__init__` i.e `__init__` of ModelForm and then you can access `fields`.

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].initial = my_random_number()
```